# Javascript functions datepicker,lazyload is not working after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I know we had to initialize javascript functions after the ajax call in success, but that too doesnt work in my case. Following is my code :

jQuery :

```
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:ajaxurl,
            data:{
                action:'get_more_posts',
            },
            success:function(data){
                 console.log(data);
                 $('#posts-inner-container').append(data); // data includes datepicker textbox
                 $('.datepicker').datepicker();
            }
        });
```

Comment: try doing $(data).find('.datepicker').datepicker();

Comment: no luck,
i also tried doing $('body').find('.datepicker').datepicker();

Comment: what is output of ` console.log(data);`?
`

Comment: I get html data with input tags :
<div class="main-container">Some content <input type="text" class="datepicker" /></div>

Comment: put your code in $(document).ready(function(){                                                                  here come your ajax request      });

Comment: I have initialized datepicker on document.ready function, but we have to reinitialize datepicker and other javascript function when we append data through ajax.

Comment: have you checked inside the container?...$('#posts-inner-container').find('.datepicker').datepicker();

Comment: okay if you are using jquery version 3 then there is a live function that will do your work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize datepicker all over the site. Use following code :

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:ajaxurl,
        data:{
            action:'get_more_posts',
        },
        success:function(data){
             console.log(data);
             $('#posts-inner-container').append(data); // data includes datepicker textbox
             $(document).find('.datepicker').datepicker();
        }
    });
```